# Dynamic radio menu items in RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm trying to populate a menu in an RCP application dynamically with radio menu items. The intention is that these menu items correspond to different "modes" for the application.

I'm creating the menu through a dynamic contribution:

```
@AboutToShow
public void aboutToShow(
        final List<MMenuElement> items,
        final EModelService modelService) {

    // Code to get list of modes

    for (Mode m : modeList) {
        final MDirectMenuItem menuItem;
        menuItem = modelService.createModelElement(MDirectMenuItem.class);
        menuItem.setType(ItemType.RADIO);
        menuItem.setLabel(m.getName());

        /* Set the "handler" instance */
        menuItem.setObject(new ModeMenuHandler(m));
        items.add(menuItem);
    }
```

When I click on the individual menu items, the corresponding handler is correctly being called. However, the menu items don't behave as *Radio* items.

**How can dynamically created radio menu items be made part of a single *radio-item-group***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that each time the menu is shown the old menu items are destroyed and the `@AboutToShow` method is called again to recreate the menu. So any old radio selection is lost.

So you would need to save the current selection each time it changes and call `setSelected(true)` on the appropriate menu item when the menu is created again.

Alternatively if the number of items in the menu doesn't change (your `modeList` is a fixed size) you could create the menu once using a processor (the `processor` element of the `org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model` extension point).

Comment: Thanks! Doing a `setSelected(true)` during the `@AboutToShow` did the trick.